# create php array using simpleXMLobject

Tags: php, simplexml, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to get this array ($resdata) with object(SimpleXMLElement) into a php array:

```
$resdata = 
array(59) { 
[0]=> ...
[10]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#294 (28) { 
["reservation_id"]=> string(7) "8210614" 
["event_id"]=> string(6) "279215"
["space_reservation"]=> array(2) { 

    [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#344 (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3760" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "205" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(33) "Center" } 

    [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#350 (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3769" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "207" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(32) "Right" } } } 
}
```

I've tried:

```
$res = (array)$resdata;
$reservation = $res['reservation'];
$result = array();

foreach ($reservation as $key => $value){
$res = array($value);
$spid = $res[0]->space_reservation->space_id;
echo $value->event_id."<br />";
echo $spid."<br />";
}
```

This only outputs the first space_id and I need to get all the space_ids within "space_reservation" array. Not all records will have multiple space_ids. Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated. Not sure if I should use xpath but I need to re-write my foreach statement regardless.

I was hoping to be able to literally convert all references to "object(SimpleXMLElement)#*_* (#)" to "array(#)"

```
[10]=> array (28) { 
["reservation_id"]=> string(7) "8210614" 
["event_id"]=> string(6) "279215"
["space_reservation"]=> array(2) { 

    [0]=> array (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3760" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "205" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(33) "Center" } 

    [1]=> array (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3769" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "207" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(32) "Right" } } } 
}
```

the function in my cakephp 1.3 controller is this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$this->data['events']= $xml->children();
$resdata = $this->data['events'];
$this->set('resdata',$resdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you are looking for:

```
foreach ($resdata as $res) {
    echo $res->event_id . '<br />';
    foreach ($res->space_reservation as $reservation) {
        echo $reservation->space_id . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to literally convert all references to "object(SimpleXMLElement)#___ (#)" to "array(#)"                [10]=> array(3) { 
["reservation_id"]=> string(7) "8210614" 
["event_id"]=> string(6) "279215"
["space_reservation"]=> array(2) { 

    [0]=> array (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3760" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "205" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(33) "Center" } 

    [1]=> array (9) { 
    ["space_id"]=> string(4) "3769" 
    ["space_name"]=> string(9) "207" 
    ["formal_name"]=> string(32) "Right" } } } 
}

Comment: I ended moving forward with a modified version of this. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Googled it and found a general solution for any SimpleXMLElement to array conversion:

```
function xml2array($xml) {
  $arr = array();
  foreach ($xml as $element) {
    $tag = $element->getName();
    $e = get_object_vars($element);
    if (!empty($e)) {
      $arr[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? xml2array($element) : $e;
    }
    else {
      $arr[$tag] = trim($element);
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Comment: this is interesting. I did see this in php.net but to be honest, I don't know how/where to implement. I already have a function in my cake controller that generates the original array $resdata which may correlate to either $xml or $arr above in your example. I just don't know but I do need to change, "object(SimpleXMLElement)#___ (#)" to something in php that I can key through. If I were to start with the foreach statement above and put that in my view, I would need to edit the $arr[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? reference to function. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @sloga can you give me original xml so I could do some testing?

Comment: could it be as simple as $tag = instanceof SimpleXMLElement($element);

Comment: @sloga no, I mean an example of XML markup :) The value of `$element` variable.

Comment: I know, I meant to ask that as a separate question, kind of thinking out loud...the $element would be the $resdata result above. I didn't include all 59.Only number 10 had a space reservation with 2 different spaces. all others (49) of them had a single space id. Should I var_dump it and chat you or email?

Comment: About my answer - you should use it just like `var_dump(xml2array($resdata));`. First try it then if you won't achieve what you need we'll continue.